3d plot of linestring geometries through plotly
I would like to plot a floor plan in 3d but my attempt creates traces for every line, which is unnecessary and results in lag when plotting floor plans with many linestrings. Is there a way to plot the floor plan in 3d using a single trace?
The floor plan from a simple plot_ly() call:

Using plotly's split argument:

Without split:

The .dxf file is in this repo.
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)
library(bslib)

dxf <- st_read("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asadow/linestring-select/main/giraffe360_demo_residential.dxf")

dxf_gp <- dxf |>
  group_by(geometry_type = st_geometry_type(dxf)) |>
  nest()

dxf_lns <- dxf_gp |>
  filter(geometry_type == "LINESTRING") |>
  unnest(cols = c(data)) |>
  mutate(
    geometry = st_zm(geometry, "LINESTRING"),
    ini = st_startpoint(geometry),
    end = st_endpoint(geometry)
  )

dxf_lns <- dxf_lns |>
  mutate(
    across(
      c(ini, end),
      list(
        x = \(point) st_coordinates(point)[,1],
        y = \(point) st_coordinates(point)[,2]
      ),
      .names = "{.fn}{.col}"
    )
  ) |> 
  st_as_sf()

df <- dxf_lns |> 
  st_coordinates() |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(Z = 0)

df |> 
  plot_ly(type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines",
          x = ~X, y = ~Y, z = ~Z, split = ~L1,
          line = list(color = '#1f77b4', width = 1))


What's the problem with split? that it shows multiple traces in the legend? If so, you can turn off the legend.

For many traces, split results in sluggish plot interaction, even with the legend off.

You could either use group_by() or turn off the legend when using split:
df |> 
  group_by(L1) |>
  plot_ly(type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines",
          x = ~X, y = ~Y, z = ~Z,
          line = list(color = '#1f77b4', width = 1))

df |> 
  plot_ly(type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines",
          x = ~X, y = ~Y, z = ~Z, split = ~L1, 
          line = list(color = '#1f77b4', width = 1), 
          showlegend = F)



group_by() does the trick (single trace). And I see this is covered in Chapter 3 of Carson's book.
